# Show captions when mouse hovers over the thumbnail menu in Jssor

Tags: javascript, html, css, jssor

I am using Jssor and wanted to know how to show a caption when the mouse hovers over one of the thumbnail menu images?  I have tried to add the title attribute to the image as so

```
<img data-u="thumb" src="images/MissionPagePics/thumb-Mission-info.png" title="Uplink tools"/>
```

nothing happened. so I did this one

```
<div data-u="thumb">
 <img src="images/MissionPagePics/thumb-Mission-info.png" />
   Uplink tools
</div>
```

Again, nothing happened.
So is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I have found, so if anyone is interested here it is:

First I removed this line

```
<div class="c"></div>
```

from the thumbnavigator, for some reason when this line is in the code the image title is not shown.

Then I copied all the css code for the .c class to the .t class, this one

```
<div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
```

Lastly, I changed the opacity from 0 to 0.5 and 1, as so

```
.jssort03 .p:hover .t, .jssort03 .pav .t {
        filter: alpha(opacity=0.5);
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

now the image caption, title, is shown when I hover on the thumbnail menu images.

cheers,

es.